# Is there a word for having more than ten fingers?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I recently read an article about a man who had twelve fingers and twelve toes.  Is there a word for this genetic anomaly?

Comment: Hello, my name is Inigo Montoya...

Comment: Someone was looking for you.

Comment: I think i know the guy you are talking about. Where he has "perfect" polydactylism. When i first saw his picture i knew something was wrong, but wasn't sure because it really looked normal.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The word is [**polydactyly**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polydactyly).  The Wikipedia link has some cool pictures and x-rays.

Comment: Just as a sidenote: polydactyly is often a dominant trait, and will be seen often in families.

Comment: I suspect they also tend to get a LOT of Princess Bride references thrown at them.

Comment: Also known as "Elite Gamer Mod" :-)

Comment: @fluffy Not as popular, but the movie [Gattaca](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119177/trivia?tr=tr0655467) had a six finger pianist in it, too.

Comment: Polydactylism (polydactyly) is [not uncommon in house cats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polydactyl_cat).

Comment: I read a science fiction story many decades ago in which the characters surmised that we used base ten because many thousands of years ago our ancestors must have had ten fingers instead of twelve. If this trait is truly dominant....

Comment: @LarsTech - They also (falsely) claimed the piece he was playing could only be performed by someone with extra digits.  Off the top of my head, I don't recall the piece, but I know I've heard it performed by normal 10-finger pianists.

Answer (score 0):

The medical term for this condition is known as [**polydactyly**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polydactyly) or *polydactylism*.

You can refer to these extra pieces of flesh as [**supernumerary**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernumerary_body_part) body parts. You can have a supernumerary amount of toes, fingers or any other body part, as list of which can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernumerary_body_part#Specific_types_of_occurrence).